# Modules are overlapping in smartdiagram

Tags: smartdiagram

I am using `smartdiagram` with large text width in `Beamer` presentation. The modules are visible but they are overlapping to each other. Below is the code-

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true,
module minimum width=4cm,
module minimum height=2cm,
text width=4cm}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{
\textit{State} $S_t$\\Table tennis player decide strategy, 
The system is transferred to new state $S_{t+1}$}
```

Below is the output-

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also specify a `module x sep`, the initial value is 2.75 which is not enough in your case.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,lmodern}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\smartdiagramset{back arrow disabled=true,
module minimum width=4cm,
module minimum height=2cm,
module x sep = 6cm,
text width=4cm}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{
\textit{State} $S_t$\\Table tennis player decide strategy, 
The system is transferred to new state $S_{t+1}$}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But shouldn't this be automatically calculated by `smartdiagram` itself?